# has anyone used CppUnitLite2 1.1?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

has anyone used CppUnitLite2 1.1?
if so could you please give  a link where I can find the full reference about this framework  not just the description on the author's home page?

Answer (score 0):

This page http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CppUnitLite says:

There are only the code and a simple example in the package. Are there any documents on how to use CppUnitLite? Or one have to figure it out by herself from the code?

The book [WorkingEffectivelyWithLegacyCode](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?WorkingEffectivelyWithLegacyCode) by [MichaelFeathers](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MichaelFeathers) uses CppUnitLite for its CeePlusPlus UnitTesting examples.